# How to run grafana via nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, grafana

I am reading through the official [Grafana behind a reverse proxy documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/behind_proxy/), but I still cannot get to see the result and I don't know why.

Here is what I did:

I added the following two type `A` DNS records, which direct to my server and have TTL of 3600.

- www.grafana.mysite.com
- grafana.mysite.com

I created the following file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/grafana.mysite.com`

Inside, the file looks like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

The I modified in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

```
[server]
domain = grafana.mysite.com
```

After that tested nginx's syntax `sudo nginx -t` and restarted the grafana server and the nginx server like so:

1. sudo systemctl restart grafana-server
2. sudo systemctl reload nginx

Yet when I go to either `grafana.mysite.com` or `www.grafana.mysite.com` I see the `Welcome to nginx!` page only :/

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the file you created is being read by Nginx? Try: `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is using. Is this file symlinked to the `sites-enabled` directory?

Comment: A good point from @RichardSmith, one more thing to check is if there is any other (e.g. default) server configured. I would suggest to add name-based virtual host https://www.tecmint.com/nginx-name-based-and-ip-based-virtual-hosts-server-blocks/ - the server_name grafana.mysite.com www.grafana.mysite.com; directive if the issue is not solved by linking the configuration to a proper place.

Comment: @RichardSmith indeed it is not symlinked...

Comment: @RichardSmith after symlinking it, I get `404 Not Found` on the webpage. Any idea why? and in my terminal I get `channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`